# django tastypie caching is not working for list data

Tags: django, python-2.7, caching, tastypie

i am using python 2.7,django=1.5 and tastypie v0.12.1 when i am hit 1 recourse data is then caching is happing

```
class BranchResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        collection_name="data"
        queryset = Branch.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'branch'
        authorization = Authorization()
        limit = 0 #(unlimted)
        filtering = {
            "branch_flag": ALL,
            "branch_name":('exact', 'startswith','istartswith',),
            "cid":ALL,
        }
        cache = SimpleCache(timeout=1000)
```

is caching is working  when i hit

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/v0/branch/1
```

but in when i getting all data then caching is not working

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/v0/branch/
```

that time caching  not work is direct hit db and getting data from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your server configuration I guess. Please edit your server configuration file as given below
(if it is nginx)
vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-site-name and  add the following line of code in the file

```
location / {

   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_cache     cache;

   }
}
```

Second thing which you have to do is create a directory/folder called cache in your project

```
Finally go to nginx.conf and edit the file like this
vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
go to line no 80
proxy_cache_path yourworkspace/projectname/cache keys_zone=cache:1m max_size=2m;
```

DONE!!! Now Caching will work fine

Answer (score 0):

From the [Tastypie documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/caching.html):

> However, it’s worth noting that these do NOT cache serialized representations. For heavy traffic, we’d encourage the use of a caching proxy, especially Varnish, as it shines under this kind of usage. It’s far faster than Django views and already neatly handles most situations.

That leaves you with two options:

- Implement your own cache class, derived from `tastypie.cache.SimpleCache` or `tastypie.cache.NoCache`, and do support iterable data types.
- Go with tastypie's advice and use a dedicated cache server.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the function `get_list` in `tastypie.resources.ModelResource` change the code

```
objects = self.obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle,**self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
```

to

```
objects=self.cached_obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle,**self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
```

Full code:

```
def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
    base_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)

    objects = self.cached_obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

    sorted_objects = self.apply_sorting(objects, options=request.GET)

    paginator = self._meta.paginator_class(request.GET, sorted_objects, resource_uri=self.get_resource_uri(), limit=self._meta.limit, max_limit=self._meta.max_limit, collection_name=self._meta.collection_name)
    to_be_serialized = paginator.page()

    # Dehydrate the bundles in preparation for serialization.
    bundles = []

    for obj in to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name]:
        bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=obj, request=request)
        bundles.append(self.full_dehydrate(bundle, for_list=True))

    to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name] = bundles
    to_be_serialized = self.alter_list_data_to_serialize(request, to_be_serialized)

    return self.create_response(request, to_be_serialized)
```

then http://127.0.0.1:8000/v0/branch/ will get cached,not only http://127.0.0.1:8000/v0/branch/1